# Replacing n occurences of a certain string in a message

Tags: javascript, performance, architecture

I am in need of a function that determines URL occurences in a message (string) and wraps them in `<a>` elements.

This is my approach:

```
function wrapUrl(message){

    var content = message.split(' ');

    content.forEach(function(item){

        // Check if this is an URL and if so, wrap it

    });

}
```

This will be used in a chatroom, thus there will be a lot of messages. Each message is a POJO holding 
3 key - value pairs.

Considering performance, is this a good approach or am I missing a easier variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
function wrapUrl(message){

    var regex = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/g;

    var message2 = message.replace(regex, function(v) { return "<a>" + v + "</a>"});

    return message2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url) out:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

if(regex.test("http://google.com")){
  alert("Successful match");
}else{
  alert("No match");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the regEx sample! However, what i really wanted to know was whether or not it is an issue that I have to split up and loop every single message in order to find the occurences (which could be multiple ones)

Comment: as long as the message is not huge, it's ok, but I'd rather message.replace.